# react native : What is the right way to change a TOAST style?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, toast

In my example I try to change the style of "toast" but for some reason it does not work for me and I do not understand why because it is exactly according to their example.

```
import Toast, { BaseToast } from 'react-native-toast-message';

export default function FOAM (props) {
const toastConfig = {
    success: ({ text1, ...rest }) => (
      <BaseToast
        {...rest}
        style={{ borderLeftColor: 'pink' }}
        contentContainerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 15 }}
        text1Style={{
          fontSize: 15,
          fontWeight: 'semibold'
        }}
        text1={'TIME UPDATE'}
        text2={null}
      />
    )
  };

return (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                <Toast config={toastConfig} ref={(ref) => Toast.setRef(ref)} />
              }
            </TouchableOpacity>
 );
   }
```

Comment: Can you show a screenshot from your toast ?

Comment: its not appear ...its not works

Comment: i made an example on snack for your code and its working, please check it out https://snack.expo.io/@hassan190011/react-native-toast-message

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I customized font size for `react-native-toast-message` in typescript:

**toastConfig.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import theme from 'assets/styles/theme';
import Toast, {AnyObject, BaseToastProps} from 'react-native-toast-message';
import SuccessToast from 'react-native-toast-message/src/components/success';
import ErrorToast from 'react-native-toast-message/src/components/error';
import InfoToast from 'react-native-toast-message/src/components/info';

const renderToast = (Component: React.FC<BaseToastProps>) => (
  props: BaseToastProps,
) => (
  <Component
    text1Style={{fontSize: theme.font.size.md}}
    text2Style={{fontSize: theme.font.size.sm}}
    onTrailingIconPress={() => Toast.hide()}
    {...props}
  />
);

const toastConfig: AnyObject = {
  success: renderToast(SuccessToast as React.FC<BaseToastProps>),
  error: renderToast(ErrorToast as React.FC<BaseToastProps>),
  info: renderToast(InfoToast as React.FC<BaseToastProps>),
};

export default toastConfig;
```

**react-native-toast-message.d.ts**

```
declare module 'react-native-toast-message/src/components/success' {}
declare module 'react-native-toast-message/src/components/info' {}
declare module 'react-native-toast-message/src/components/error' {}
```

**Root.tsx**

```
const Root = () => (
  <>
    <Toast config={toastConfig} ref={ref => Toast.setConfig(ref)} />
  </>
);
```